# how can set variables from ffprobe

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffprobe

how can i add artist title date etc. to variables?

```
from ffprobe import FFProbe

metadata = FFProbe("01-leo_lausemaus_-_leo_lausemaus_titelsong.mp3")
print(metadata)
```

output results its:

```
<FFprobe: {'title': 'Leo Lausemaus Titelsong', 'artist': 'Leo Lausemaus', 'track': '1/0', 'album': 'Folge 1', 'disc': '1', 'date': '2015', 'TLEN': '78', 'album_artist': 'Leo Lausemaus', 'Duration': '00:01:18.99', 'start': '0.025056', 'bitrate': '329 kb/s'}, [<Stream: #1 [video] Motion JPEG, 0, (512x512)>], [<Stream: #0 [audio] MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3), channels: 2 (stereo), 44100Hz> ], [], []>
```

I want to be able to output each variable individually

I use python 3.8 on windows.

Regards

Comment: Have you tried a `dir(metadata)`? That should give you some hints as to what methods and attributes are available.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how to do that, can you tell me how i can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the [source](https://github.com/gbstack/ffprobe-python/blob/master/ffprobe/ffprobe.py), the metadata you're seeing [in the repr](https://github.com/gbstack/ffprobe-python/blob/master/ffprobe/ffprobe.py#L110) is an instance attribute, `metadata`, [which is a dict](https://github.com/gbstack/ffprobe-python/blob/master/ffprobe/ffprobe.py#L66). So to get the title for example:

```
metadata.metadata['title']
```